# Auto scale android resources

Tags: android, image, resources, widget

I have *.png in drawable-hdpi.
I want android autoscale down for drawable.

- mdpi.
- ldpi.

but no scale up for:

- -xhdpi .
- xxhdpi.

What i can do?.
i search in google and don't find nothing.
Someone can help me?.

i don't want put the same png in xhdpi and xxhdpi because it only gonna make my apk more large, and the users see it and don't download the app if it is too big.

i put (is a widget) something like this:

```
      RemoteViews views;
       views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.wilayout);
       views.setImageViewResource(R.id.motivo, The id of the resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the image you wish to use to the drawable-nodpi directory with an alternate name to it's drawable name.

Then in drawable-ldpi create an alias to the drawable with the 'real' drawable name you wish to use using a drawable alias (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources)

Finally, in drawable-xhdpi create a scale drawable with the same 'real' name and a scale of 1, the source being the -nodpi counterpart (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Scale)

This way, by preference, the scaling drawable should be used for ldpi-hdpi and xhdpi should prefer the fixed-scale drawable. Try it out

Comment: but i think with your idea i can put the real png with the real name in hdpi and put the scale archive in xhdpi and xxhdpi, if it dont work i gonna use the other.i think it gonna do downscale hdpi-lhdpi,and not scale to xxhdpi and xhdpi

Comment: i try it,how u say and it don't work, the widget dont display it directly for xhdpi

Comment: It was worth a try, -nodpi seems to have different behaviour across android versions anyway. 
Your best bet is to just add the -hdpi resource and programatically scale it down in xhdpi and above by detecting the screen type